# Is it possible to make a fuzzy blanket material without using a particle system?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, particles

I know that it's possible to make a fuzzy blanket with a particle system, but it seems like I should be able to do it with just a material + cloth simulation. Here is the effect that I'm looking for:

[image: blanket]

I think it could be done with some combination of fresnel, velvet, and normal maps, but I'm not great with materials. If anyone can offer some advice, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, your looking for a cycles material, not a real time rendering or blender internal solution, right?

Answer (score 3):

You can always go in and tweak it more, but this gets ya close.

I guess, to explain a bit...

*Object info: Random* gives a range from 0-1,
so I send that into a multiplier to get the desired range,
then pass it into a texture.

Contrast on voronoi seemed too intense, so I subtracted a tiny amount.

I gave it a bit of subsurf to make it look soft, but then it looked oversaturated,
so I used the HSV node to dim the saturation slightly there.

[image: shader]

[image: blankie]

Comment: I'm a bit confused about why you're using `random` from `Object info`. According to [the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/input/object_info.html), this `random` will only give one random value for the entire object, which will not have a visible effect unless you have multiple objects.

Comment: As you'll see, I use different multipliers from that point, so each shader will get different values.

Comment: That is pointless, as RM said the random value is only different on a per object basis, it is always the same within the same object. You are only getting different values from the multiplication alone, which is the same as just entering a static value.

Comment: (random number * 800)  is different from  (random number * 12)

Comment: That isn't the point here since (constant number * 800) is also different from (same constant number * 12).  The point in these comments is that the input number is not random to begin with, it is **constant** per object. You could swap out the `Object Info` node with a `Value` node set to 19 (or any other constant value) and have the same effect.

Comment: Who really cares?  We're talking about fuzz here.  Pick a number that looks good for your render.